# Sort faster in racket using hash table

Tags: sorting, hash, scheme, racket, fold

So I have an example list of elements like this

```
(define A (list 'a 'c 'd 'e 'f 'e 'a))
```

Now I want to make a ranking from this sample

```
(define (scan lst)
    (foldl (lambda (element a-hash) (hash-update a-hash element add1 0))
           (hash)
           lst))
```

The result should be like this:

```
> #(('a . 2) ('f . 1) ('e . 2) ....)
```

Because `scan function will make a hash table containing unique keys and the number of repetitions of that key (if it catches an unindexed key it will create a new place for that new key, counting from 0).

Then I'd like to sort that hash-table because it's unsorted:

```
(define (rank A)
     (define ranking (scan A))         
     (sort ranking > #:key cdr)))
```

So the result would look like this:

> #(('a . 2) ('e . 2) ('f . 1) ...)

Now I'd like to truncate the hash-table and throw away the bottom at the threshold of n = 1 (aka only take the elements with more than 2 repetitions).

```
(define (truncate lst n)
    (define l (length lst))
    (define how-many-to-take 
        (for/list
             ([i l]
               #:when (> (cdr (list-ref lst i))
                          n))
               i))
    (take lst (length how-many-to-take)))
```

So the result might look like this:

> (('a . 2) ('e . 2))

However, at the big scale, this procedure is not very efficient, it takes too long. Would you have any suggestion to improve the performance?

Thank you very much,

**Part 2:**

I have this data structure:

```
(automaton x 
   (vector (state y (vector a b c))  
           (state y (vector a b c)) ...))
```

Then i generate randomly a population of 1000 of them. Then i scan and rank them using the above functions. If i just scan them as is, it already takes long time. If i try to flatten them into a list like this

```
(list x y a b c y a b c...)
```

it'd take even more time. Here is the flatten function:

```
(define (flatten-au au)
  (match-define (automaton x states) au)
  (define l (vector-length states))
  (define body
    (for/list ([i (in-range l)])
      (match-define (state y z) (vector-ref states i))
      (list y (vector->list z))))
  (flatten (list x body)))
```

The scan function will look a bit different:

```
(define (scan population)
    (foldl (lambda (auto a-hash) (hash-update a-hash (flatten-automaton auto) add1 0))
           (hash)
           population))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, I believe I see the problem. Your algorithm has O(n^2) ("n-squared") running time. This is because you're counting from one to the length of the list, then *for each index*, performing a `list-ref`, which takes time proportional to the size of the index.

This is super-easy to fix.

In fact, there's really no reason to sort it or convert it to a list if this is what you want; just filter the hash table directly. Like this...

```
#lang racket

(define A (build-list 1000000 (λ (idx) (random 50))))

(define (scan lst)
    (foldl (lambda (element a-hash) (hash-update a-hash element add1 0))
           (hash)
           lst))

(define ht (scan A))

(define only-repeated
  (time
   (for/hash ([(k v) (in-hash ht)]
              #:when (< 1 v))
     (values k v))))
```

I added the call to `time` to see how long it takes. For a list of size one million, on my computer this takes a measured time of 1 millisecond.

Asymptotic complexity is important!

Comment: Thank you I'm quite newbie in Racket.

Isn't for/hash also goes through the whole hash?



Now the computer spends most of its time in scan function. Would you have any suggestion on that?

I write a for/fold loop for the scan function but it works more or less the same.

Comment: In answer to your question: yes, `for/hash` goes through the whole list. The difference is that your original solution went through the whole list, and for each of them, went through the whole list! (Actually, it went through only part of the list, but let's not get bogged down in a discussion of asymptotic complexity). To address your second question: how long is your list, and how long is the scan taking?

Comment: It's too long so i add part 2 into my question.

Comment: You're only including part of your code; it's really hard to help you without being able to see everything. Perhaps you should just create a gist (e.g. using gist.github.com) with running program?

Comment: It's really a big mess and involves many different things. I'm still working on it. If I can break it down into a better question, I'd post it here. Thank you for your help, Chi